# Wix recreate deleted shortcut when reinstalling

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm learning about shortcuts in Wix and have managed to create shortcuts on the desktop.

If I delete the shortcut and then run the installer again I would like the shortcut to be created again.
How can this behavior be achieved with Wix?

I have created shortcuts both with

```
    <File Id="TestX.exe" Name="TestX.exe" Source="$(var.TestX_TargetDir)TestX.exe">
      <Shortcut Id="desktopIcon" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="TestX" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLFOLDER' Icon="IconTestX.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
```

and

```
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="DesktopShortcut"
                 Guid="1E0D1741-57F0-4E22-89FC-4A189E2BB7E0">

        <Shortcut Id="desktopSC"
                  Name="MyProduct"
                  Description="MyProduct description"
                  Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]TestX.exe"
                  Icon="IconTestX.exe">
        </Shortcut>
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder"
                      Directory="DesktopFolder"
                      On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                       Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"
                       Name="installed"
                       Type="integer"
                       Value="1"
                       KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
```

Comment: When you say "run the installer again" does that mean run a repair or actually install again (as in an upgrade)?

Comment: I assume it was just an install/upgrade. I didn't specify that there should be an repair, just ran the (very simple) msi-file without any options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using WixUI_InstallDir in the WixUI library, which added a GUI which includes the option to start a repair.

Links about the WixUI dialog library: 
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html